# Problem painting through model in overlapping uv area

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I'm trying to texture paint this model but there is a problem at the hand guard area at the front of the gun. I want to paint through the model to get both sides while in right view. I turned off occlude in the options to do this but then I get the problem. There are overlapping uv's in this area from the barrel inside the hand guard. I hid the inside barrel's uv's/mesh in edit mode to paint but when I go into texture paint they are visible again.
[image: A1 Show]

Blend file [image]

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but why not just move the overlapping uvs (from the barrel) to a blank space in the uv layout?  I was able to do this without too much difficulty.

Comment: Yes I can do that and probably will. Thought about it after posting but there are other models with the same kind of set up so I'm not sure if that will always work. This one is from a game so I can't change the important uv's.

Comment: The uv unwrap is bad then, fixing it is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the uv's to an unused space will work.

From the blender manual for v2.79 overlapping uv's are not supported:

"**Known Limitations**

**UV Overlap**

In general overlapping UVs are not supported (as with texture baking).

However, this is only a problem when a single brush stroke paints onto multiple faces that share a texture."

So the only solution really is to delete the part or move the problem uv's to an area that is not used. The original uv's are set by someone else but since the part is not seen it doesn't matter.